# EIZO monitor with an integrated KVM switch loses the USB connection to the mouse and keyboard after standby mode

Tags: display, kvm-switch, multiple-computers

[How can I avoid windows being rearranged when I use my KVM switch?](https://superuser.com/questions/1720453/how-can-i-avoid-windows-being-rearranged-when-i-use-my-kvm-switch/1831205#1831205)

**@Ramhoud**:
You wrote: "...Your KVM obviously doesn’t do this." Is this a KVM problem or a Windows one. I have the same problem with my new EIZO EV3240x. The first computer (laptop) on the USB-C port has no problems with switching, but the stationary PC (connected via display port and USB-B) can no longer wake up after it falls into standby mode. EIZO claims it is Windows because the USB connection to the KVM port is not held in standby mode.
I checked all power plan settings (setting for selective energy saving) and BIOS, but unfortunately nothing worked.
Is there any other solution to this without purchasing a new monitor with KVM functionality?

Comment: Please phrase your question as its own post. This is not a threaded forum and so while you have included links to a related question, your arranging of this post does not immediately indicate your question stands on its own and is not, in fact, simply a comment on the other question. If your question is different from the other and not answered by the answers on the other post, make it clear it stands on its own, while the other only provides some context or indicates what you have already tried, etc.

Comment: The post can be deleted. THX